# Passing a Dynamically Created Array as an Argument

Tags: c++, arrays, function, memory, dynamic

Can someone help me figure out how to pass a dynamically created array as function argument.

I've created a 2D dynamic array as follows:

```
//matrix rows and columns
int rows=0;
int cols=0; 


int** matrix = new int*[rows]; 

//creates the matrix
for (int i =0; i < rows; ++i)
    matrix[i] = new int[cols];
```

I'd like to pass this array into a function with a prototype like this:

```
void readMatrix(int **matrix[], int size);
```

I can't figure out how to do this! I don't know what the argument should look like, I've tried many different ways and none work. Getting errors that say "expecting expression" or "argument doesn't match parameter"

Comment: Note: The preferred (modern) way of doing it would be using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of raw arrays

Comment: Wouldn't you just pass it in like: `readMatrix(matrix, size)`

Comment: `int **matrix[]` this is basically `int ***matrix`. So you pass it like `&matrix`.

Comment: Tried doing that and get the following: "argument of type int** is incompatible with parameter of type int***"

Comment: @GillBates ah! Works! Thanks! That makes sense too.

Comment: @UnholySheep: `std::vector` has been "modern" for nigh 20 years...

Comment: Off topic: Compared to Antikythera, the Difference Engine is modern. 20 years is nothing. More on topic, making an array of arrays can have a severe performance impact on processing because of poor spatial locality. All of those arrays are different arrays in different locations in memory, so the CPU has a harder time preloading the cache for high-speed data access.

Answer (score 2):

The function specifies the `int **matrix[]` for the type, which is equivalent to a type `int ***matrix`. So what you need is another indirection. Use `&matrix` as an argument.

Also, as mentioned in comments, re-think the whole idea of using the plain arrays in favor of a more modern `std::vector<>` one.